# How to run Kivy apps on Windows on VirtualBox?

Tags: windows, opengl, virtualbox, kivy

I wrote an application using Kivy and it runs well on Linux (Ubuntu).

When it comes to run it on Windows which is a guest os in VirtualBox, it gives the error:

```
[INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[WARNING           ] [Input       ] WM_Touch/WM_Pen not supported by your versio
n of Windows
[DEBUG             ] [Base        ] Create provider from mouse,disable_multitouc
h
[DEBUG             ] [Base        ] Create provider from wm_touch
[WARNING           ] [Base        ] Unknown <wm_touch> provider
[DEBUG             ] [Base        ] Create provider from wm_pen
[WARNING           ] [Base        ] Unknown <wm_pen> provider
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
OpenGL Warning: SHCRGL_GUEST_FN_WRITE_READ (1048740) failed with ffffffdb ffffff
ea
```

Yes, I have read OpenGL section in VirtualBox documentation. Yes, I have enabled 3D acceleration. Yes, I have installed GuestEditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Kivy application works as expected. I should have rechecked that if my os setup was really correct.

Here is what I did:

1. Uninstalled currently installed guest additions (since VirtualBox might be upgraded in time)
2. Installed fresh GuestAdditions with 3D acceleration option checked. (in safe mode)
3. Restarted system, run the application.